# ASP.Net MVC request ViewModel not parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a request like this:

```
filter[logic]:and
filter[filters][0][value]:a
filter[filters][0][operator]:startswith
filter[filters][0][field]:result
filter[filters][0][ignoreCase]:true
```

I need to receive it on the Controller but I don't know exactly how. I have tried this view model:

```
{
    public class SearchFilterViewModel
    {
        public string logic { get; set; }
        public List<SearchFilterFiltersViewModel> filters { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchFilterFiltersViewModel
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        //public string operator { get; set; }
        public string field { get; set; }
        public bool ignoreCase { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But the Controller receives it all null. `operator` property is commented because operator is a reserved keyword, I don't know how to make Asp.Net to use it. And I don't know if this is the cause of the problem.

Note that I can't change the request body pattern because it comes from [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html) Kendo Widget.

This is my Controller(test version):

```
public ActionResult Text(SearchFilterViewModel filter)
{
    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Just to verify, is it POST method?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Nope, GET.

Comment: Hm, as usual such data should be posted by POST method, not GET. otherwise it can be hard to specify List in it

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov A GET request is the semantically correct way of passing search filters.

Comment: The operator param is not the cause of the problem. You can include it by defining the class as a DataContract and the properties as DataMembers (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx). Every DataMember can then have a Name, this is the name it should be parsed from/in.

Comment: Does DataMembers used by MVC Value providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution

Model:

```
public class SearchFilterViewModel
{
    public string logic { get; set; }
    public List<SearchFilterFiltersViewModel> filter { get; set; }
}

public class SearchFilterFiltersViewModel
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string oper { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public bool ignoreCase { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write custom [IValueProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ivalueprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) where you can override usual parsing mechanism like this:

```
public class KendoValueProvider : NameValueCollectionValueProvider
{
    public KendoValueProvider(NameValueCollection originalCollection)
        : base(UpdateCollection(originalCollection), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
    }

    private static NameValueCollection UpdateCollection(NameValueCollection collection)
    {
        NameValueCollection result = new NameValueCollection();

        foreach (string key in collection.Keys)
        {
            // ignore all other request
            if (!key.StartsWith("filter"))
                return null;

            var newKey = key
                .Replace("[filters]", string.Empty)
                .Replace("filter[logic]", "logic")
                .Replace("[value]", ".value")
                .Replace("[operator]", ".oper")
                .Replace("[field]", ".field")
                .Replace("[ignoreCase]", ".ignoreCase");

            var value = collection[key];

            result.Add(newKey, value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you need to write ValueProviderFactory that will register this ValueProvider like this:

```
public class KendoValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        return new KendoValueProvider(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString);
    }
}
```

And the last step is just register it in Global.asax file

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new KendoValueProviderFactory());
```

And sample Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(SearchFilterViewModel model)
{
      return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: My queryString is this: `?filter%5Blogic%5D=and&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=a&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=startswith&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=result&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BignoreCase%5D=true&_=1388335983036`

Comment: You don't need to append model name to each property. So, if you remove filter from each property in queryString, then it should work.

Comment: Sorry but as I said on the post, the problem is that the request body is made by the widget, I have no influence on it. I can't change it.

Comment: I've updated answer with working solution based on this queryString

Comment: Dude, thank you for this answer, but I though this becomes very complicated, so I changed the script to send **mine** request - not Kendo's anymore - and it worked. Thank you again. I'll mark this as accepted.